# Facebook ads insights for inactive/paused campaign

Tags: facebook, ads, facebook-insights

I am getting blank result when I tried to retrieve information regarding inactive campaign statistics using Graph API explorer.
e.g.

`/v2.10/xxxxxxxxxx/insights?level=campaign&filtering=[{'field':'campaign.delivery_info','operator':'IN','value':['inactive']}]&date_preset=last_month&fields=impressions,ctr,cpc,clicks,campaign_name,call_to_action_clicks,total_action_value,spend`

Result:

```
{
  "data": [  ]
}
```

Regards
Shah